# Initialize a pointer to primitive to a temporary object

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, initialization, constants

I think that this is valid code **in MSVC**:

```
MyClass* pMc = &MyClass();
```

However, when I try to do the same thing with primitive data-types I'm getting a compilation error.

```
int* pInt = &int();
```

Error:

```
error C2101: '&' on constant
```

I have 3 questions:

1. Why does `int()` give me a constant?
2. Why does error [C2101](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4asz0fdf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) exists in the first place? what's wrong with getting the address of a constant?
3. Is there a way I could declare int (or other primitive) references that point to temporary objects? (that is, without creating a local variable first)

About the 3rd question:

I do **not** want to do something like this:

```
int i = int();
int* pInt = &i;
```

If I'm working with references to local objects (the reasons why are irrelevant), I don't want to have to declare each and every object twice. It's tedious, annoying and the names would be really confusing.

Comment: You do realize `int()` is potentially the same as `0`? So your statement is effectively equivalent to `&0`, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Also `&MyClass()` is not a completely valid code, it shouldn't compile. MSVC++ stupidly allows it.

Comment: Non-const references to temporaries are disallowed by the standard, though MSVC has an extension to circumvent that. Best not to try to hack together a solution with undefined behaviour.

Comment: @David Did not realize it's exactly the same as 0. why doesn't it give me an object?. Seth Carnegie Chris explained why it did compile. Thank you all.

Comment: `completely valid code` Oh?

Comment: `the reasons why are irrelevant` No, not really.

Comment: `It's tedious, annoying and the names would be really confusing` Make them non-confusing. It's not hard.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The code compiles on MSVC, read the comments. the reasons are irrelevant because I'm asking about the language. It's still annoying.

Comment: @Ken: That it compiles on MSVC is irrelevant because you are asking about the language and that is not valid C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Didn't know that before I've asked the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the answer to 1 (I think the error is wrong, because I'm pretty sure `int()` is not a constant), but

(2) Taking the address of a temporary is illegal. Your code shouldn't compile but it does because of a nonstandard MSVC++ extension.

(3) Yes, use rvalue-references or const lvalue-references:

```
const int& tmp = int();
int&& tmp = int(); // same as former but isn't const
```

The lifetime of the temporary will be prolonged until the reference goes out of scope.

However, I hope you have a good reason for using one of the two above rather than

```
int tmp;
```

Comment: The fact that it's an extension explained everything. And as I mentioned in the comments, I don't have any reason, I'm asking about the language. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The line of code compiles in one compiler in a way that violates the standard, but dereferencing that pointer is undefined behavior on the very next line.  So be careful.

I think this might work:

```
template<typename T>
T* make_tmp_ptr(T&&t) {
   return &t;
}
```

Then call `make_tmp_ptr(int())` and you will get a pointer to a temporary `int` that will last until the end of the expression.